# How to determine the best location (country) for an email server?

Tags: email-server

Is there any advantage to have an email server in the same country as the email account holders?

**Example:**

All emails are from people of country A. They send and receive emails mainly from/to country A.

Is there any difference to have an email server in Country A with ping < 20ms or in Country B with ping < 75ms.

Both are in Europe and use cpanel/whm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless account holders on the mailserver, and recipients are in the same local network, the traffic will head out to the internet anyway, so you won't see much bandwidth savings.  Remember what sysadmins always say:  Mail Is Not an Instant Messaging Protocol ;)  Besides, the difference in ping times you reference are likely minimal compared to the time spent filtering the messages for spam.

Comment: my concern was only about sucess delivery, or lost emails.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason to have a mail server in the same country should be to have it under the same applicable local laws.

Apart from that latency is not important for e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

The longer the distance, the longer it will take to retrieve the email....afterall the amount of hardware increases and the bandwidth between two underlying internal connections can well have a dramatic effect.